# Microsoft Outlook 2010: Increase Depth of Conversation View

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Outlook 2010, I have the following problem. I use a discussion view on my folders so that I can see conversation threads as a tree. But it seems not to go to the full depth.

The lower levels of the conversation tree are summarized into single items that look like one giant message object. When you scroll through it, you can see the individual message headers and bodies.

The problem is that some of those messages are sometimes addressed to me and require a response from me.  These are, firstly, hard to notice (I have to ferret them out)  and then they are impossible to reply to.

To reply to such a message, I have to turn off the discussion view so that the message becomes accessible as a stand-alone object.

Is there some way to configure Outlook not to have this behavior, and just keep all messages in a threaded view individual?  It looks as if the Conversation View is not actually proper threading. In that case, is there some extension that makes Outlook have proper threading?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use another client, instead of or in parallel with Outlook, that provides real threading, such as Thunderbird.